# vsftpd: 550 Permission denied trying to uploading/writing files

Tags: ftp, vsftpd

I've created a user jdoe and I wanted to map such a user to apache user. So everytime that I upload a file could be owned by apache.

This is my /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf file:

```
listen=YES
listen_ipv6=no
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
ascii_upload_enable=YES
ascii_download_enable=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
chroot_list_enable=YES
ls_recurse_enable=YES
pam_service_name=vsftpd
rsa_cert_file=/etc/vsftpd/www.example.com/fullchain1.pem
rsa_private_key_file= /etc/vsftpd/www.example.com/privkey1.pem
pasv_enable=Yes
pasv_min_port=1030
pasv_max_port=1035
ssl_enable=yes
debug_ssl=yes
force_local_logins_ssl=YES
force_local_data_ssl=YES
allow_anon_ssl=no
ssl_ciphers=HIGH
ssl_tlsv1=YES
ssl_sslv2=NO
ssl_sslv3=NO
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
guest_enable=YES
chmod_enable=YES
chown_uploads=YES
chown_username=apache
guest_username=apache
hide_ids=YES
user_config_dir=/etc/vsftpd
```

And I have in /etc/vsftpd/jdoe :

`local_root=/var/www`

But when I upload o create a file I get:

> 550 Permission denied

(on Filezilla)

Am I doing something wrong? Is what I'm looking for feasible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've found a way:

```
listen=YES
listen_ipv6=no
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
log_ftp_protocol=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
ascii_upload_enable=YES
ascii_download_enable=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
chroot_list_enable=YES
ls_recurse_enable=YES
pam_service_name=vsftpd
rsa_cert_file=/etc/vsftpd/www.example.com.ar/fullchain1.pem
rsa_private_key_file= /etc/vsftpd/www.example.com.ar/privkey1.pem
pasv_enable=Yes
pasv_min_port=1030
pasv_max_port=1035
ssl_enable=yes
debug_ssl=yes
force_local_logins_ssl=YES
force_local_data_ssl=YES
allow_anon_ssl=no
ssl_ciphers=HIGH
ssl_tlsv1=YES
ssl_sslv2=NO
ssl_sslv3=NO
pasv_address=192.168.222.11
guest_enable=YES
chown_uploads=YES
chown_username=apache
guest_username=apache
hide_ids=YES
user_config_dir=/etc/vsftpd
anon_upload_enable=YES
anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES
anon_other_write_enable=YES
anon_umask=0002
```

And also:

in `/etc/vsftpd/jdoe`:

```
local_root=/var/www/www_example_com_ar
```